# Pivileges of a new user in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, privileges

I used to work with Oracle, where after creation of a new database user you need to grant them a few privileges, ex. to connect(CREATE SESSION) to the database or create a table(CREATE TABLE). Otherwise the user is useless and literally can nothing.

1. How does it work in Postgres? Why after CREATE USER statement and assigning SCHEMA to him, I'm able to log-in, create schema/ objects and much more things?
2. How to display user privileges? I would like to know how powerfull the user is.

Example:

```
CREATE USER test_user WITH PASSWORD 'abc';      
CREATE SCHEMA test_user ;   
ALTER SCHEMA test_user OWNER TO test_user ;
```

Now I can log-in as test_user and do a lot of things in the database.

Comment: Is this the section of the manuals you need? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html

Comment: I haven't found there answers to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL manages these things differently from Oracle.

Oracle has all these annoying<sup>1</sup> "system privileges"; PostgreSQL manages this via schema permissions: if a user has the `CREATE` privilege on a schema, she can create arbitrary objects in that schema.

There is no way to list all privileges of a role in PostgreSQL. You could try an extension like [pg_permissions](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_permissions/) and its `all_permissions` view.

---

<sup>1</sup> to me, at least — why can't I create a view on my own table by default?

Comment: I'm aware of that fact, but my questions remain still unanswered: how powerfull is the test_user? How to display his "system privileges"? I have created a user and I don't know which statements can he run and which not...

Comment: System privileges are in my opinion very nice feature, because it provides much more flexibility than in Postgres/Sql Server. Let's say that you want to GRANT to a user privilege to CREATE a table, without possibiltiy to CREATE a VIEW - in Oracle this is feasible, in Postgres/Sql Server not - as far as I know..

Comment: I never want to allow a user to create a table, but forbid them to create a view. As I said, I was always annoyed by that. But you are of course free to feel otherwise. I added an answer to your second question (but please follow the rule of "one question per question" in the future).

Comment: Grant TABLE but not VIEW, does that make any sense? A view is just a pre-defined query.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html

> CREATE USER is now an alias for CREATE ROLE. The only difference is that when the command is spelled CREATE USER, LOGIN is assumed by default, whereas NOLOGIN is assumed when the command is spelled CREATE ROLE.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html

> GRANT — define access privileges
> Specific types of privileges, as defined in Section 5.7.

Section 5.7
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html

> 5.7. Privileges

> When an object is created, it is assigned an owner. The owner is normally the role that executed the creation statement. For most kinds of objects, the initial state is that only the owner (or a superuser) can do anything with the object. To allow other roles to use it, privileges must be granted.

<...>

> The available privileges are:

> SELECT

> A whole list of specific privileges and what they mean for different objects